# How to fix "+CME ERROR: unknown network message" error while sending USSD command to the gsm modem?

Tags: gsm, at-command, modem, ussd

I am trying to execute USSD codes through my GSM modem. When i try USSD command which gives me some option, it is executed but i can't get any operation done from the options.

AT+CMGF=1

OK
AT+CSCS="GSM"

OK

AT+CUSD=1,"*101#",15 (To check balance)

OK

+CME ERROR: 264

AT+CUSD=1,"*17108#",15 (To get a data pack)

OK

CUSD: 1,"1.Datapacks
 .Voicepacks
 .SMS Packs
 .Billing info
 ote:
Back:* Top:#",15

AT+CUSD=1,"1"

OK

+CME ERROR: 264